# Why does DOMDocument use 80 minutes when XMLParser use 10 seconds to parse 120MB of XML?

Tags: php, performance, xml-parsing, domdocument, libxml2

I have a large 120MB XML file, and i have written 2 parsers to parse it, 1 with the [DOMDocument API](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php), which ***uses roughly 80 minutes*** to parse it, and another parser using the [XML Parser API](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.xml.php), ***using roughly 10 seconds*** to parse it. (I also wrote a SimpleXML-based parser at some point, but it was no faster than DOMDocument, i think it was even slower, and i didn't keep the code)

that's an insane performance difference! why?

CPU: mid-range 2018 Intel Laptop CPU ([Intel Core i7-8565U](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/149091/intel-core-i78565u-processor-8m-cache-up-to-4-60-ghz.html))

PHP version: PHP 8.2.1

why the crazy performance difference? due to the difficulty of hosting large text files, i've zstd-compressed it and base64 encoded it down to 8.7MB, the original XML can be obtained with:

```
wget 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/divinity76/02dd2b9ab596bd1fd31d1c2e5a72075a/raw/895cfb598f6c5ebdf5837e593113c1c072e7cb5e/ellos.xml.zstd.b64' -O- | \
base64 -d | \
zstd -d > ellos.xml
```

the integrity can be confirmed with b3sum

```
cat ellos.xml | b3sum
3d27fe1ed272b91dc25f2f81c2920dec091f0e536866d5dedd74bd74fca303bf  -
```

both versions should run something like

```
ini_set("memory_limit", "3G");
```

the DOMDocument-based parser code is:

```php
function ellos_xml_file_to_item_array(string $xml_file_path): array
{
    // due to the large size of the xml file,
    // which API is used to parse it can be the difference between
    // an hour of parsing, or 10 seconds of parsing.
    // DOMDocument parser: ~80 minutes
    // alex-oleshkevich/php-fast-xml-parser (based on XMLParser): ~10 seconds
    // however XMLParser is difficult to use,
    // php-fast-xml-parser has issues with PHP>=8.2 and UTF-8 ( https://github.com/alex-oleshkevich/php-fast-xml-parser/issues/9 )
    // and we don't have time to fix it, so we use the slower DOMDocument parser
    $domd = new DOMDocument();
    $domd->load($xml_file_path);
    $itemsNodeList = $domd->getElementsByTagName("item");
    $items_parsed = [];
    foreach ($itemsNodeList as $itemNode) {
        $item = [];
        foreach ($itemNode->childNodes as $childNode) {
            if ($childNode->nodeType !== XML_ELEMENT_NODE) {
                if ($childNode->nodeType === XML_TEXT_NODE && trim($childNode->nodeValue) === "") {
                    // whitespace "nodes"
                    continue;
                }
                // investigate other node types
                throw new LogicException(var_export(["UNEXPECTED NODE TYPE", $childNode->nodeType, $childNode->nodeName, $childNode->nodeValue], true));
            }
            $item[$childNode->nodeName] = $childNode->nodeValue;
        }
        if (false) {
            // sample:
            $item = array(
                'Discount_Percentage' => '30%',
                'g:id' => '1650866-02',
                'g:availability' => 'in stock',
                'g:condition' => 'new',
                'g:description' => 'Väst i lätt vadderad modell med randig quiltstickning.  •  Rak modell •  Dragkedja med skavskydd vid hakan •  Hög krage •  Infällda sidfickor med dragkedja •  Smal ribbmudd nertill fram •  Längd ca 67 i stl M',
                'g:image_link' => 'http://assets.ellosgroup.com/i/ellos/ell_1650866-02_Fs?w=1661',
                'g:link' => 'https://www.ellos.se/jack-jones/vast-jjluke-light-vest/1650866-02-L',
                'g:title' => 'Jack & Jones - Väst jjLuke Light Vest',
                'g:price' => '599.00 SEK',
                'g:gtin' => '5715095009566',
                'g:mpn' => 'Jack & Jones1650866',
                'g:brand' => 'Jack & Jones',
                'g:additional_image_link' => 'http://assets.ellosgroup.com/i/ellos/ell_1650866-02_Fs?w=66,http://assets.ellosgroup.com/i/ellos/ell_1650866-02_Fs?w=33,http://assets.ellosgroup.com/i/ellos/ell_1650866-02_Fs?w=665,http://assets.ellosgroup.com/i/ellos/ell_1650866-02_Fs?w=342,http://assets.ellosgroup.com/i/ellos/ell_1650866-02_Fs?w=152',
                'g:color' => 'Grön',
                'g:gender' => 'Male',
                'g:item_group_id' => '1650866',
                'g:product_type' => 'Herr>Mode>Jackor & rockar>Västar',
                'g:sale_price' => '419.00 SEK',
                'g:custom_label_0' => '',
            );
        }
        $items_parsed[] = $item;
        //echo "parsed: " . count($items_parsed) . "\r";
    }
    //echo "deserialised to php array, time: " . (microtime(true) - $t) . "s\n";
    return $items_parsed;
}
```

and the XML Parser-based parser code is:

```php
function ellos_xml_file_to_item_array_optimized(string $xml_file_path): array
{
    // this is a highly optimized, but difficult to read/maintain, parser.
    // the speed difference is INSANE on 120MB document:
    // DOMDocument parser: ~80 MINUTES,
    // xml_parser: ~10 seconds
    $parser = xml_parser_create();
    xml_parser_set_option($parser, XML_OPTION_CASE_FOLDING, 0);
    xml_parser_set_option($parser, XML_OPTION_SKIP_WHITE, 1);
    xml_parse_into_struct($parser, file_get_contents($xml_file_path), $vals, $index);
    xml_parser_free($parser);
    unset($parser);
    $items_parsed = [];
    $is_in_item = false;
    $current_item_level = null;
    $item = [];
    foreach ($vals as $key => $val) {
        $type = $val["type"];
        $tag = $val["tag"] ?? null;
        if (!$is_in_item && $tag !== "item") {
            continue;
        }
        $level = $val["level"];
        if (!$is_in_item && $tag === "item") {
            assert($type === "open");
            $current_item_level = $level;
            $is_in_item = true;
            continue;
        }
        if ($tag === "item" && $type === "close") {
            // finished with an item.
            if (false) {
                // sample:
                $item = array(
                    'Discount_Percentage' => '40%',
                    'g:id' => '1650894-04',
                    'g:availability' => 'in stock',
                    'g:condition' => 'new',
                    'g:description' => '•  Vid, finstickad modell •  Rund halsringning •  Nerhasad axel •  Ribbstickade kanter ',
                    'g:image_link' => 'http://assets.ellosgroup.com/i/ellos/ell_1650894-04_Fs?w=1661',
                    'g:link' => 'https://www.ellos.se/moss-copenhagen/troja-femme-mohair-o-pullover/1650894-04-XSS',
                    'g:title' => 'Moss Copenhagen - Tröja Femme Mohair O Pullover',
                    'g:price' => '799.00 SEK',
                    'g:gtin' => '5712808579095',
                    'g:mpn' => 'Moss Copenhagen1650894',
                    'g:brand' => 'Moss Copenhagen',
                    'g:additional_image_link' => 'http://assets.ellosgroup.com/i/ellos/ell_1650894-04_Fs?w=66,http://assets.ellosgroup.com/i/ellos/ell_1650894-04_Fs?w=33,http://assets.ellosgroup.com/i/ellos/ell_1650894-04_Fs?w=665,http://assets.ellosgroup.com/i/ellos/ell_1650894-04_Fs?w=342,http://assets.ellosgroup.com/i/ellos/ell_1650894-04_Fs?w=152',
                    'g:color' => 'Brun',
                    'g:gender' => 'Female',
                    'g:item_group_id' => '1650894',
                    'g:product_type' => 'Dam>Mode>Tröjor & koftor>Stickade tröjor',
                    'g:sale_price' => '479.00 SEK',
                    'g:custom_label_0' => '',
                );
            }
            $items_parsed[] = $item;
            //echo "parsed items: " . count($items_parsed) . "\n";
            $item = [];
            $is_in_item = false;
            $current_item_level = null;
            continue;
        }
        $item[$tag] = $val["value"] ?? "";
    }
    return $items_parsed;
}
```

fwiw

```
    $t = microtime(true);
    $domd->load($xml_file_path);
    echo "DOMDocument load time: " . (microtime(true) - $t) . "s\n";

DOMDocument load time: 2.3969311714172s

    $t = microtime(true);
    $itemsNodeList = $domd->getElementsByTagName("item");
    echo "DOMDocument getElementsByTagName time: " . number_format(microtime(true) - $t, 9) . "s\n";die();

DOMDocument getElementsByTagName time: 0.000005960s

    $t = microtime(true);
    xml_parse_into_struct($parser, file_get_contents($xml_file_path), $vals, $index);
    echo "xml_parse_into_struct time: " . number_format(microtime(true) - $t, 9) . "s\n";die();

xml_parse_into_struct time: 4.495072126s
xml_parse_into_struct time: 2.977376938s
xml_parse_into_struct time: 2.852163076s
xml_parse_into_struct time: 2.776274920s
xml_parse_into_struct time: 2.799090862s
```

Comment: DOMDocument needs to read the whole document in one go, whereas if I am not mistaken the XML parser API is stream-based.

Comment: @CBroe you CAN use the "XML parser API" stream-based, but that's not what i did here, i read the entire file in 1 go with ```xml_parse_into_struct($parser, file_get_contents($xml_file_path), $vals, $index);```

Comment: Try timing just the parsing part, `DOMDocument::load` vs. `xml_parse_into_struct`.

Comment: @rustyx thanks, added to post: DOMDocument::load uses about 2.3 seconds. xml_parse_into_struct() uses about 4.5 seconds. the problem is not there.

Answer (score 0):

From looking at your benchmark code, we can notice a couple of things:

- When you use DOMDocument, you call `$domd->getElementsByTagName("item")` which I assume means it will go through the whole document to find all elements tagged "item" then return them into `$itemsNodeList` and then you loop again through each item to construct the data arrays.
- When you use XMLParser, you are doing these 2 steps at the same time with `if ($tag === "item" && $type === "close") {` which reduces the time complexity.

The code from XMLParser is less readable but with a little refactoring, like moving the code in `//finished with an item.` into a function that constructs the element and adding some comments, it can become a good part of your codebase. Hope I could shed some light.

Comment: fwiw ```$domd->getElementsByTagName("item")``` finishes in 0.000005 seconds (5 microseconds), so that should be irrelevant ^^  - top post updated

Comment: welp, that throws off my answer